# executescript in python not passing flow file to next processor

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am trying to run executescript process in Apache Nifi using python but having problem with passing flow file to next processor in my data flow.

If I run the standalone flow file creation and writing snippet  it works and I can read flow file in the next processor but when I try to enrich it, it simply does not pass the flow file. In fact no error is generated and somehow I have no clue how to proceed. I am bit new with python and nifi and appreciate your help with this particular issue.

Below is the code I am using and you can see its very simple. I just want to create and write some string to flow file using some logic. But no luck so far

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time
import sys
import traceback
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil

class WriteContentCallback(OutputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content_text = content

    def process(self, outputStream):
        try:
            outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(self.content_text))
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise

page_id = "dsssssss"

access_token = "sdfsdfsf%sdfsdf"

def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
        flowFile = session.create()
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("Hello there this is my data"))
        flowFile = session.write()
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)           
        print "\nDone!\n%s Statuses Processed in %s" % \
                (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the check for `__main__`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
```

`__builtin__` was the actual module name in my experiment.  You could either remove that check, or add a different one if you want to preserve your separate testing path.